# old prelim exam question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

In studying for my prelims, I can't quite come up with a solution to the following problem, from a few years ago. It has the feel of a "write the correct thing down, and it's 3 lines" problem.

Problem statement: Let $u:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be absolutely continuous, satisfy $u(0)=0$, and $\int_0^1|u'(x)|^2dx<\infty$. Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{u(x)}{x^{1/2}}$ exists and determine the value of this limit.

Thoughts/Attempt: Absolutely continuous means the FTC applies so we have $u\in L^1$, $u'\in L^1\cap L^2$, $u(x)=\int_0^xu'(t)dt$, and $u(0)=0$. The last condition means we can use L'Hopital's rule on the limit, so

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x)}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}2\sqrt xu'(x)$.

A few things come to mind immediately, but don't quite do the trick. There's some very basic bound on $u'(x)$ which I'm being stupid about seeing, can anyone please offer a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: This was one of the things that came to mind but I couldn't get to work. Puts a bound on $\|\sqrt x u'\|_{L^1}\leq\|\sqrt x\|_{L^2}\|u'\|_{L^2}<\infty$. Maybe Holder inequality, says that $\|\sqrt x u'\|_{L^1(0,\epsilon)}\leq\|\sqrt x\|_{L^\infty(0,\epsilon)}\|u'\|_{L^1(0,\epsilon)}=\sqrt\epsilon u(\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$, but that still doesn't mean that $\sqrt xu'(x)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, by the way. I'm sure once it becomes clear I'm going to hit my head through the door.

Comment: $|u(x)| = \left|\int_0^x u'(t)\; dt\right| \le \ldots$

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please take a look at the answer I posted? It doesn't have the feeling of being ``right,'' and it doesn't make use of given conditions or Cauchy-Schwarz. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I eventually came up with was: by difference quotient,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}u'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x)-u(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x)}{x}$,

and therefore

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x)}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}2\sqrt x u'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}2\frac{u(x)}{\sqrt x}$,

and therefore

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{u(x)}{\sqrt x}=0$.

However, this doesn't use the fact that $u'\in L^2$, which we don't need because we already know $u\in W^{1,1}$ by virtue of being absolutely continuous...

Comment: There's no reason for $\lim_{x \to 0} u'(x)$ to exist.
All absolute continuity gives you is $u' \in L^1$.
For example, $u(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is absolutely continuous, and $u'(x) = 1/(2 \sqrt{x})$ for $x \ne 0$.